# Cloud platform for scala web application (like heroku)

Tags: scala, web, cloud

I'm new to Scala world, I want to write a web application with Scala and deploy using a cloud platform (like heroku or open shift).

The problem is I used play framework (v2.2) with heroku and faced quite a lot of problems handling my data files. I finally decided to let go of Play framework.
Now, what choices do I have ?
I would use pure Scala (instead of using frameworks) if I have to, but don't know where to start.

**UPDATE:**
My application is very simple and has only a few pages, but It is used to upload image files and that's where I had problem with play and heroku.
So, to summarize, I won't need most features of usual web frameworks, I just need a minimal framework and a cloud platform (like heroku) to deploy my application in it.

Comment: *Like Heroku* means PaaS? (on contrary to IaaS, which is Amazon EC2, for example). By the way your question is offtopic for SO, voted for closing.

Comment: heroku, cloudbees, clevercloud, and many other paas allow for scala application deployment with or without play2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options, so it all depends on what your application does. One choice you should consider is to use a JavaScript single-page web application framework like [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) in combination with a Scala REST framework like [Scalatra](http://www.scalatra.org/) or [Spray](http://spray.io/).

Or maybe you don't need Angular or similar at all and can just get by with a simple template engine like [Dust](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/) or [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) templates on the front end.

Comment: Thanx for your fast reply, I've updated my question to provide more details

Comment: Looks like Scalatra is the one I was looking for. thanx a lot

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!